# Default Role Provider could not be found in iis 6 and asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I'm launching asp.net mvc 3 apllication on ii6. No membership or role providers are used. I have implemented authorization by creating authorization cookie manually, and handled it in global.asax. First of all a have got this error:

Access denied creating App_Data subdirectory 
Description: For security reasons, the identity 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0' (under which this web application is running), does not have permissions to create the App_Data subdirectory within the application root directory. ASP.NET stores the Microsoft SQL Express Database file used for services such as Membership and Profile in the App_Data subdirectory of your application.

I have searching for this error, and add this to my web.config file, as a solution:
in `<system.web>` node:
    `<roleManager enabled="false">
    <providers>
    <clear />
    </providers>
    </roleManager>`

and in `<modules>` node in `<system.webServer>`:
`<remove name="RoleManager" />`

and then got 'Default Role Provider could not be found' error.

What I did wrong?

Comment: <remove name="RoleManager" />  =  'Default Role Provider could not be found' error ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. IIS6 does not recognize `<system.webServer>` (it was introduced in IIS7), and I used `<httpModules>` in `<system.web>` instead:

```
<system.web>
...
<httpModules>
<remove name="RoleManager" />
</httpModules>
...
<system.web>
```