# Default Role Provider could not be found on IIS 7 running .NET 4

Tags: c#, iis, web-applications, membership-provider, roleprovider

Good morning all,

I am attempting to implement my custom membership and role providers in my web application that I have implemented under the Default Web Site in my instance of IIS 7. My web application is running under a .NET 4 application pool.

However, after setting up the corresponding web.config, I get the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Default Role Provider could not be found.
```

I have included the following block of code in the system.web section of the corresponding web application's web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
 <providers>
  <clear/>
  <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="CustomProviders.CustomMembershipProvider,   
     CustomProviders, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
     PublicKeyToken=3563615169617648" applicationName="/"/>
 </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
   <clear/>
   <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="CustomProviders.CustomRoleProvider, 
     CustomProviders, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
     PublicKeyToken=3563615169617648" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Now I have seen all sorts of explanations as to how solve the error that I mentioned earlier. Most of them seem to suggest that I add  tags to my provider blocks.
Some seem to suggest that [I remove the role manager from the machine.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128533/default-role-provider-could-not-be-found-in-iis-6-and-asp-net-mvc-3). And some still seem to suggest [not removing or adding anything.](http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.com/2012/05/default-membership-provider-could-not.html) This last approach does not seem to account that my web application is being run from IIS and not a local machine.

In the end, I have have tried these approaches to little avail. Can someone please explain to me how I can get passed this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got this error when using the default MVC 4 web application.
I had to add the following to web.config and the error went away.
Under `<system.webServer>`
add

```
<modules>
 <remove name="RoleManager"/>
</modules>
```

Comment: You amazing person. I was stuck on this stupid issues, just all of a sudden out of the blue. And tried so many things before this.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

`enabled="false"` should probably be `enabled="true"`

And I'm not convinced the `applicationName="/"` is helpful, but it may not be hurting, either.

Comment: Sorry the enabled attribute was copied over wrong when asking the question. Enabled is in fact set to true, and I still get the above error. As far as the applicationName, the "/" seems to be fairly common practice. I am not sure what to use alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when adding an application in IIS 8 to our existing web site (Right-click on the website in IIS, select "Add Application").  The application's web.config only had the default  tag, which was removing the default provider that the web site's web.config defined.

I removed the RoleManager tags completely from the application's web.config, and then the website and application started working properly.