# How do I stop using ASPNETDB.MDF in LocalDB?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, .net-4.5, asp.net-identity

I implemented ASP.NET Identity and it automatically created ASPNETDB.MDF and aspnetdb_log.ldf in my App_Data folder. I already have the AspNet tables (i.e., AspNetRoles, AspNetUsers, etc) in my SQL Express instance (which is where all my other tables are sitting). As far as I can see, my application is reading and writing membership and role data from the SQL Express database and not ASPNETDB.MDF.

I have set my connectionString in web.config to:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

However, if I remove ASPNETDB.MDF from App_Data, I get the following error when I login:

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: One or more files do not match the primary file of the database. If you are attempting to attach a database, retry the operation with the correct files.  If this is an existing database, the file may be corrupted and should be restored from a backup.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'MyComputerName\MyUserName'.
Log file 'C:\Users\MyProjectName\App_Data\aspnetdb_log.ldf' does not match the primary file.  It may be from a different database or the log may have been rebuilt previously

The error goes away once I add ASPNETDB.MDF back to App_Data.

I have searched all the code in my solution and it makes no reference to ASPNETDB. So why is it still trying to read from it?

I am developing ASP.NET web forms on .Net 4.5.

Comment: Did u edit this connection string with valid one..    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcApplication7-20141218122456;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcApplication7-20141218122456.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: My connection string is already connectionString="Data Source=MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True". It is not pointing to any MDF file but to my SQLEXPRESS database.

Comment: what is the NAME of this connection stringconnectionString="Data Source=MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"   it should be same as <add name="DefaultConnection"  ...

Comment: @Aswartha my full connection string is:
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MyComputerName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 5):

I was getting exactly the same problem. I discovered that VS annoyingly pulls in config settings from machine.config, which lives outside of the project, in my case in...

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
```

Identity 2.0 had used the following connection string inside machine.config...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

to set up a connection for...

```
       <membership>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, ........" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

.. (which was also set in machine.config). If you haven't been using Membership then it's fine to do as Lord nick suggests (except just the clear/ will do the job) and simply do the following in web.config...

```
<connectionStrings>
   <clear/>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="whatever" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

However, if you, like me, previously had Membership running (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t(v=vs.100).aspx), you will need to comment out or delete the following sections from machine.config...

```
<!--
    <membership>
        <providers>
        ...
        </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
        <providers>
         ...
        </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager>
        <providers>
        ..
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
-->
```

... since all this stuff is no longer needed for AspNet Identity 2.

I also had to add the following into  in my web.config:

```
<modules>
 <remove name="RoleManager"/>
</modules>
```

... as per this answer: [Default Role Provider could not be found on IIS 7 running .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857825/default-role-provider-could-not-be-found-on-iis-7-running-net-4)

I hope I've saved someone some time. This took me hours and hours to work out.

Comment: I spent all day on this with a app deployed to an Azure app service.  This worked perfectly, had to add LocalSqlServer connection string pointing to prod db in web.config.

Comment: thanks a lot! Adding `<remove name="RoleManager"/>` helped to stop generating this ASPNETDB.MDF file. I'm not sure why since I already had `<roleManager enabled="false" />` in web.config...

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This was melting my head! @clayRay

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Problem where the ASPNETDB.MDF was automatically created, even if I use Asp.Net Identity as the main user management.

I solved it by removing the following line from web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

This one tells ASP.NET to use the older ASP.NET Membership user management, which is not supported by ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have something like in your web.config

```
<add name="DefaultConnectionForLocalDb" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;..."; />
```

In your `AccountModels.cs` file, you have:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnectionForLocalDb")
    {
    }
}
```

However it should be this way:

```
<add name="DefaultConnectionForSQLEXPRESS" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;...;" />

public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnectionForSQLEXPRESS")
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can remove safely `DefaultConnectionForLocalDb` entry from your `web.config` and `ASPNETDB.MDF` from to `App_Data`.

Comment: I think my web.config code didn't show up in the first post. I have added it in. Basically I am already pointing the my SQL Server database, not the localDB. I don't have AccountModels.cs.

Comment: Where does membership initialize?

Comment: My apologies. I meant to say that I implemented ASP.Net Identity, not Membership. Do you still need to know where Identity initializes? (I'm not sure where to find that answer, actually.)

Comment: No problem. Then this question has different scope

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've figured this out or not but one of the things you can try is: in `web.config`, `connections` section, add `<Clear/>` and then `<Remove Name=LocalSqlServer/>`

Apparently if you don't change/remove the `LocalSqlServe` will still try to connect to the aspnetdb.mdf.

You might also think about adding back in the `LocalSqlServer` and having it point to your SqlExpress or SqlServer.