# Local App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF keeps being created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Writing an MVC5 app. For some reason, a local App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF db keeps being created, even though in my web.config the only db I specify is a totally different one on the network (and is working fine.) What could be creating this db (and recreating, if I delete it)? I searched my solution for ASPNETDB.MDF and nothing appears, so it's not in any type of config file, etc....

The connectionStrings section of my web.config....

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="ZZZ_SpringContext" />
  <add name="ZZZ_SpringContext" 
       connectionString="Data Source=mypc\sql2012;Initial Catalog=ZZZ_Spring;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

***** UPDATE *****

I tried deleting the db again. Then in my web.config I changed the rolemanager line to false and the db is NOT recreating now. That helps me to see what is creating the db. But, how can I get around this? Here's the line in the web.config....

```
    <roleManager enabled="false" />
```

I had to change it back to "true" so my app would work correctly.

Comment: Maybe the AspNet Identity? What tables do you see when you open the database using Visual Studio or SSMS?

Comment: @maxbeaudoin I am using Identity but all tables are in the db defined in the web.config. I couldn't view the contents of the ASPNETDB.MDF db. I included it in my project and went to open and it said "This db file is not compatible with the current instance of SQL Server." Every time I delete it and run the app it is recreated.

Comment: Can you include the connectionStrings section of your web.config?

Comment: @maxbeaudoin I included it above. Thanks

Comment: @maxbeaudoin See my update above

Comment: Generated ASPNETDB database often comes from `Membership` or `SimpleMembership` provider with automatic DB creation enabled, which somehow uses `Membership` functionality before completing DB initialization process, which created ASPNETDB database in `App_Data` folder. Include your controller code which possibly contain `Authorize` or `InitializeSimpleMembership` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I had nearly same problem where ASPNETDB.mdf file still recreate even it already deleted. It turns that ASP.NET Identity instance uses `machine.config` file outside the project which has the following line:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And in the end of configuration file I found the `membership` element, which seems controlling `Membership` provider behavior:

```
<system.web>
    <membership>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
</system.web>
```

Note that `connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"` refers to ASPNETDB.mdf as shown in `connectionStrings` element before.

Then, in web.config inside the project, this line determines if `RoleManager` instance is enabled:

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

The lines given above tells that ASP.NET Membership provider is enabled as current user management, which defeats purpose of ASP.NET Identity.

Hence, if the ASPNETDB.mdf database is not exist & `Membership` provider support being enabled, the `Membership` provider will initialize with default configuration settings in machine.config, and automatically generates ASPNETDB.mdf and its log file using default table definitions.

To prevent re-creation of that DB, in addition to change `<roleManager enabled="false">`, you can use these steps in web.config:

1. Clear existing or predefined connection strings before defining your own.

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <remove name=LocalSqlServer /> <== this is maybe optional
      <add name="ZZZ_SpringContext" 
      connectionString="Data Source=mypc\sql2012;Initial Catalog=ZZZ_Spring;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
   ```
2. Remove `RoleManager` provider in module definition.

   ```
   <modules>
     <remove name="RoleManager" />
   </modules>
   ```
3. Comment out all `membership`, `profile` & `roleManager` elements if necessary to do so.
4. If your account model code has `UsersContext` class, ensure it pointed to current connection string defined on your own.

   ```
   public class UsersContext : DbContext
   {
       public UsersContext() : base("ZZZ_SpringContext")
       {
       }
   }
   ```

Related issue:

[How do I stop using ASPNETDB.MDF in LocalDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540744/how-do-i-stop-using-aspnetdb-mdf-in-localdb) (WebForms version)