# ASPNETDB.MDF is being created in my MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I've had my database for years that includes the `AspNet` tables as shown in the image below
[image]

Any new user that was created was appearing correctly in the `AspNetUsers` table.

In my MVC web application in the `Startup` class I have the following `ConfigureAuth` method (pretty much out of the box code)

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
    // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
    // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

    // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
    //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
    //    clientId: "",
    //    clientSecret: "");

    //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
    //   consumerKey: "",
    //   consumerSecret: "";

    //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
    //   appId: "",
    //   appSecret: "");

    //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
    //{
    //    ClientId = "",
    //    ClientSecret = ""
    //});
}
```

My web.config connection string is as follows

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But, about a week ago I got an error complaining about an ASPNETDB.MDF file in my App_Data folder. I checked whats in this ASPNETDB database and it contains the following tables.

[image]

When I create a user through my application its still adding them into the original database and not the ASPNETDB.MDF database, which is what I want.

I deployed the latest code changes to my production site and I'm getting errors complaining about the ASPNETDB.MDF file.

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
> C:...\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name
> exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC
> share.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why I'm getting this error, and more importantly what did I do for my application to start creating this ASPNETDB.MDF file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had already tried answers in this thread and they didn't work. But once I posted this I tried again and it solved the error that was appearing.

[How do I stop using ASPNETDB.MDF in LocalDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540744/how-do-i-stop-using-aspnetdb-mdf-in-localdb)

The answer that worked was from clayRay